# CSS and Javascript / jQuery - Facebook like collapsible DIV Sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

How to create collapsible DIV sections like in Facebook - General Account Settings page?

Any plug-ins? I specially looking for some plugin that allows for collapsible divs where only one div is visible at a given time and when you click on another div, the previous one is closed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jquery UI Accordion

Demo & usage here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

It's possible to theme to your likings.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jQuery UI Accordions](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion). Sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at jQuery accordion which does just what you're after:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI's accordion plugin:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible

Then read this post to implement AJAX functionality, as in Facebook:
[How do I load content in JQuery Accordion via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880845/how-do-i-load-content-in-jquery-accordion-via-ajax)